# hibernate not mapping the bean, returning Object List

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

hi
am new and hibernate is driving me crazy full time. 
i hv 2 tables one-2-one mapping. when i join only these 2 these two then hibernate is not mapping and when i join table1 with some other table3 then its giving me fine mapped results.

Bean1

```
private int id ;
private BlessUser blessUser ;
private SnsAuthenticator snsAuth ;
public void setSnsAuth(SnsAuthenticator snsAuth) {
    snsAuth.setSnsUserId(getId());
    this.snsAuth = snsAuth;
}
```

HBM file

```
<one-to-one name="snsAuth" class="com.utilami.model.SnsAuthenticator" property-ref="snsUserId"
  cascade="all"></one-to-one>
```

Bean2

```
private int id;
private int snsUserId;
private String key;
private String value;
```

HBM file
normal hbm...

Executing lik:

```
    Session session = Utility.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from SnsUser su join su.snsAuth sa where su.blessUserId =1");
    List list = query.list();
```

This query works fine

```
String query = "from BlessUser bu join fetch bu.snsUser su where bu.id = su.blessUserId and bu." + "UserName" + " = " + "'qw'";
```

many thanks in advance.
thx

Answer (score 0):

```
from SnsUser su join fetch su.snsAuth sa where su.blessUserId = :id
```

The `fetch` keyword was missing.